# Randomize Multiple Text File and Compile into One

Tags: text, random

So, a little idea I'm working on and I'm missing one piece of it. I'm not sure what language of coding to go about this in but I'm sure it can be done it most, so any with experience in your favourite language, I could really use your help!

In an example, lets say I have multiple text files (hundreads of them!), each text file has multiple lines. What I'm looking to do is when I run program/script, it'll compile all the text files in to one text file, but in a random order each time.

Google didn't really give me anything solid on this idea. So any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

Problem solved thanks to the help of [code-monkey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/979148/code-monkey). This is his work with a bit of an alter to it to do what I wanted. Thanks everyone for the help. :)

```
import os
import random

os.chdir("C:/Users/USERACCOUNT/test/txtfiles")
directory = "C:/Users/USERACCOUNT/test/txtfiles"
extension = ".txt"
files = [file for file in os.listdir(directory) if file.lower().endswith(extension)]

file = open("C:/Users/USERACCOUNT/test/result.txt", "a")

random.shuffle(files)

for x in files:

    f = open(os.getcwd() + "\\" + x, "r")
    res = f.read()
    file.write(res + "\r\n")

f.close()
file.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i really like python for things like this, it's very easy.

here is an example:

```
import os
import random

files = os.listdir("C:\\Your\\Directory\\")

file = open("result.txt", "a")

random.shuffle(files)

for x in files:

    f = open(os.getcwd() + "\\" + x, "r")
    res = f.read()
    file.write(res + "\r\n")

f.close()
file.close()
```

hope that helps!

Comment: Looks promising! Thanks a lot! But will this randomize the compiled file as well?

Comment: nah, but i added how to make it random, it uses the random.shuffle() function

Comment: Gave it a shot, for some reason the source of the script ads itself in to the compiled text file, also nothing is spaced per line correct, it's all bunched up. :(

Comment: well,the source should not be in the file, i ran it on my machine and it works perfect, also the text being bunched up just add the "\r\n" to the output, i'll put it in the post

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot for your help! Just had a to change up something really quick after doing a google search (no idea if it was required or not, Python isn't my best subject, but it works). I put it up in my first post with your credit. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

something like this.. c#

```
static void ManyFilesToOne() {
        string dir = @"c:\miscworking\myfiles";
        FileInfo[] files = new DirectoryInfo(dir).GetFiles("*.txt");
        List<int> usedIdx = new List<int>();

        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        Random rnd = new Random();
        while (usedIdx.Count < files.Length) {

            int idx = rnd.Next(0, files.Length);
            while (usedIdx.FindIndex(delegate(int i) { return i == idx; }) >= 0) {
                idx = rnd.Next(0, files.Length);
                                }

            usedIdx.Add(idx);
            str.Append(File.ReadAllText(files[idx].FullName));
        }

        File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(dir, @"File\BigFile" + rnd.Next(10000) + ".txt"), str.ToString() + System.Environment.NewLine);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use autodie;
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Find;
use File::Slurp;
use List::Util qw( shuffle );

my $path = shift or die "Usage: $0 PATH\n";
open my $fh_output, '>', 'compiled.txt';

my @filenames;

sub compile {
    push @filenames, $File::Find::name unless -d;
}
find( \&compile, $path );

for my $filename ( shuffle @filenames ) {
    my $content = read_file $filename;
    print $fh_output $content if defined $content;
}

close $fh_output;
```

Comment: I installed activeperl on my windows machine and gave it a shot, I got this error. Am I missing something in my installation?

C:\Users\Dustin>C:\test\TEST.PL
Can't locate File/Slurp.pm in @INC (@INC contains: C:/Perl64/site/lib C:/Perl64/
lib .) at C:\test\TEST.PL line 8.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:\test\TEST.PL line 8.

C:\Users\Dustin>

Comment: Install [`File::Slurp`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::Slurp). From the command-line: `ppm install File-Slurp`.